# refund invoice api support by square

Tags: square-connect, square

I have created invoice and want to test refund invoice.  As per documentation refund api does not support invoice refund.  https://developer.squareup.com/docs/invoices-api/overview#refund-an-invoice .  Any pointers on how to support refund for invoice using API ?

Refund invoice can be done using dashboard, is it possible using API ?

Is it possible to Get paymentId based on InvoiceId and then use it with existing refund api ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation that you provided, it is not currently possible to refund an invoice via the API at this time unfortunately.